# plotly не получается настроить скорость анимации

Tags: python, plotly

Всем добрый день!
Использую plotly streamlib для создания dashboard'а, использовал параметр animation_frame. при запуске анимации показывался график выработки относительно каждого сотрудника. Анимация переключения очень быстрая, параметр animation_frame_duration не помогает, какие есть варианты настроить скорость, а так же цикличность(когда анимация доходит до последнего сотрудника она останавливается).

```
df = pd.read_excel(
            io = excel_file,
            sheet_name = sheet_name,
            usecols = "A, E:G, I",
            header = 6
            )

fig = px.bar(df, 
             x="Бренд", 
             y=["Сумма текущий", "Сумма план"], 
             barmode='group',
             color_discrete_sequence=["#FF0000", "#00FF00"], 
             animation_frame="Менеджер", 
             facet_col_wrap=4,  
             facet_row_spacing = 0.7, 
             width=1700, 
             height=600,
             )
```

Comment: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-slow-down-animation-in-plotly-express/31309/5

Comment: @strawdog Благодарю Вас. Прогугливал но на эту страницу не натыкался, выручили. Можете оставить ответом я проголосую за ваш.